# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver (with copy local set to true)

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, nhibernate

I even added to app.config this little piece of config:

```
<qualifyAssembly partialName="Oracle.DataAccess"
             fullName="Oracle.DataAccess,
                            Version=2.112.2.0,
                           Culture=neutral,
                           PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </assemblyBinding>
```

... with no success. What could be wrong?
Also, just to be sure that my app.config is feng shui, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration"
    type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">
        NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver
      </property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string_name">
        GuitarStore2
      </property>
      <property name="connection.provider">
        NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
      </property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="GuitarStore"
    connectionString="****************"/>
  <add name="GuitarStore2"
    connectionString="****************"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <qualifyAssembly partialName="Oracle.DataAccess"
             fullName="Oracle.DataAccess,
                            Version=2.112.2.0,
                           Culture=neutral,
                           PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

For the record, I am using the latest Nhibernate (3.3.1), on .NET 3.5, under Windows 7 64 bit. And, with the exact same project, I encounter no exceptions on another machine, but with Windows XP.

Comment: After trying to use MS's ADO.NET provider for Oracle, I got another interesting error: "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed." I have the feeling that the same thing happened with the Oracle Provider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem wasn't NHibernate, but the fact that the IL was generating 64 bit code, whilst using the 32 bit version of ODP, so by simply changing the "Any CPU" option to "x86", I got rid of the exception.